# What is the meaning of the lists of numbers in the FullForm of a compiled function?

Tags: compile

For example,

```
f = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, x];
FullForm[f]
```

has this output:

> ```
> CompiledFunction[List[10, 10.`, 5468], List[Blank[Real]], 
>  List[List[3, 0, 0], List[3, 0, 0]], List[], List[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], 
>  List[List[1]], Function[List[x], x], Evaluate]
> ```

What are these lists for and what do the numbers in them mean?

Comment: Effectively opcodes/allocations/value definitions. Search site for compiler tools, do a compile print, connect the dots...

Comment: I know about CompilePrint, but none of its output seems to correlate with these lists.

Answer (score 2):

The thing to do is to compare lots of different options and see what comes out. Ultimately what you're doing is taking the `FullForm` of this object:

[image]

```
$Version
(* 10.1.0  for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015) *)

FullForm[Compile[{{x, #}}, x]] & /@ {_Real, _Integer, _Complex}
```

This returns `List[10, 10.1, 5468]` for all 3 cases, so I would guess at 10 and 10.1 signifying the Mathematica version number.

The first difference in the `FullForm` is `List[Blank[Real]]`, and the corresponding result for `_Integer` and `_Complex`. This should be self-explanatory - it tells you the argument types.

Then we get something of the form: `List[List[i, j, k]...]` for the function arguments, where in this case:

- `i` is 2 for `_Integer`, 3 for `_Real` and 4 for `_Complex`
- `j` is the rank of the argument (e.g. `j = 2` for `{x, _Real, 2}` to pass a matrix).
- `k` I'm not sure yet.

The rest will be left to explore in your own time, e.g. by trying more variables, variables of different types and ranks, and also returning different things (e.g. a scalar or vector output).

The last points to make are:

- The number `5468` appears to change depending on values of  `CompilationOptions`, `RuntimeOptions` and `RuntimeAttributes`
- Compiling to C will also show the location of the compiled object

Comment: +1.   English colloquialism police here.  You would *hazard* a guess, not *hesitate* a guess.

Comment: @bobthechemist good spot, thanks!